# Codename One dragged-over container quickly dissappears

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, codenameone

I have an Android application that uses drag and drop operations. I haven't used drag and drop often, so I am just starting to learn how they work and what the implications might be.

In my app, whenever I drop the component over the target, the target sort of "flashes", meaning it disappears for a brief moment and than reappears again.

Here a [link](https://1drv.ms/v/s!AmM9-8Lwxyu2ue5wQxTJlCdp_PEQOg?e=mFqK27) to the video with the app in its current stage.

I suppose this is due to the animation of the form. If so, how can I disable it, or stop the target from flashing?

Below is my code. It is still rudimentary, since I just started to work on the project.

```
public void testDrag () {

    Container containerDropTarget = new Container();
    Container container = new Container(new GridLayout(5,1));
    Label label = new Label("test test test test test test");
    Button buttonTwo = new Button("Test");
    
    buttonTwo.addDragOverListener(l-> {
        containerDropTarget.setUIID("DialogTest");
    });
    
    containerDropTarget.setUIID("LetterHolder");
    
    buttonTwo.setDraggable(true);
    containerDropTarget.setDropTarget(true);
    
    container.add(label).add(containerDropTarget);
    
    form.add(container).add(buttonTwo);
    form.show();
}
```

Comment: Transition only happens when the form shows. Also setting it to null is wrong. It's by default empty. 
I also notice ClassCrossWords accepts containerLetterHolder then assigns it a new value. That might be related
I'm guessing the effect you're seeing is because target didn't implement the drop behavior in the way you expect. How did you implement drop?

Comment: Shai, I have changed the code sample to a smaller snippet that shows how I implement the drag and drop operation. The result of the quick disappearance is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the UIIDs defined so I used this code based on your test case and it worked correctly. I also added a label to the drop container so it could be found:

```
Container containerDropTarget = new Container() {
    @Override
    public void drop(Component dragged, int x, int y) {
        super.drop(dragged, x, y); 
        setUIID("Container");
    }
};
containerDropTarget.add(new Label("Drop Target"));
Form form = new Form("Test Drag", BoxLayout.y());
Container container = new Container(new GridLayout(5,1));
Label label = new Label("test test test test test test");
Button buttonTwo = new Button("Test");

buttonTwo.addDragOverListener(l-> {
    //containerDropTarget.setUIID("DialogTest");
    containerDropTarget.getAllStyles().setBgColor(0xff0000);
    containerDropTarget.getAllStyles().setBgTransparency(0xff);
    containerDropTarget.repaint();
});

containerDropTarget.setUIID("LetterHolder");

buttonTwo.setDraggable(true);
containerDropTarget.setDropTarget(true);

container.add(label).add(containerDropTarget);

form.add(container).add(buttonTwo);
form.show();
```

Comment: Many thanks for this complete answer and the code sample. I'll only have time to work on it after the weekend, but I'm confident it'll work. If I have any further issues, I will get in touch.